# How get Active Directory user password from java

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I need to get list with users login and password for authentication from Active Directory. I found many examples how work with LDAP Active Directory but there nothing was about how to get password. I'll be appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Minus it's great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: For getting better help sooner, consider posting your attempt(codewise).

Comment: To Celt and Sandeep. In my question i wrote that i didn't find example with getting the password, so what i should try or attempt?

Comment: You need this why? Any system that retrieves passwords is inherently suspect from the security point of view. Large corporations have suffered major embarassments and probably undisclosed losses because of practices like this.

Comment: I'm need to develop jsp page that authenticate corporate users by AD LDAP login and password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/292767/any-way-to-see-an-active-directory-password) addresses the general question of accessing active directory passwords. To summarize:

- The password field itself is write-only, so you can't query for it. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680851(v=vs.85).aspx.
- The AD administrator can set up a filter which logs password changes, including the plaintext passwords. These could be stored somewhere where they're accessible to a java program.
- The AD administrator can configure AD to hash stored passwords in a way that's reversible. If AD is configured that way, then someone with access to the database underlying the AD installation could decrypt the hashed passwords.

If you're in a position to implement one of the workarounds--and you can tolerate the reduction in security--then it becomes a simple matter of implementing the workaround, then developing a java interface to the now-insecure passwords. If you're not able to implement one of the workarounds, then you're very likely not going to have access to AD passwords.